# Не умирает процесс (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi

Привет. После закрытия окна процесс не хочет умирать.

```
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace DirectX;

HWND g_hWnd=NULL;
HINSTANCE g_hMainInstance=NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HRESULT initWindow(HINSTANCE, int);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    g_hMainInstance = hInstance;
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    //ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = g_hMainInstance;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MyName1";

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Eroare la inregistrarea clasei!", L"Eroare", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    g_hWnd = CreateWindow(L"MyName1", L"Window_1",
        WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX| WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        0, CW_USEDEFAULT,0, (HWND)NULL, NULL, g_hMainInstance, NULL);
    if (!g_hWnd){
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Eroare la crearea ferestrei!", "Eroare", MB_OK);
        return -1;
    }
    ShowWindow(g_hWnd,nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(g_hWnd);

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (true){
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, g_hWnd, NULL, NULL,PM_REMOVE)){
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hMainWnd, UINT uMessage, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
    HBRUSH brush;
    switch (uMessage){
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hMainWnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hMainWnd, &rect);
        brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200, 120, 50));
        FillRect(hdc, &rect, brush);
        EndPaint(hMainWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam){
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            MessageBox(NULL, L"A fost tastata tasta A.", L"Informatie", MB_OK);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hMainWnd, uMessage, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А `WM_QUIT` приходит?

Comment: Нет, не приходит.

Comment: Окей, а `WM_DESTROY`?

Comment: Хм, а тут да, входит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я не уверен на все 100%, но думаю, что проблема в холостом цикле

```
while (true) {
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, g_hWnd, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Этот код «гонит» холостой цикл вне зависимости от того, есть или нет сообщения (в случае, если сообщений нет, `PeekMessage` возвращает 0, и цикл продолжается!). Возможно, это не даёт возможности пройти `PostQuitMessage`.

Попробуйте более идиоматичный код

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Цикл завершится сам по приходу `WM_QUIT` (в этом случае `GetMessage` вернёт 0).

---

Microsoft [советует](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) более строгий код:

```
BOOL bRet;

while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0)) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // обработать ошибку и выйти
    }

    TranslateMessage(&msg); 
    DispatchMessage(&msg); 
}
```

Comment: Да, в цикле была проблема. Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: @Romeon0: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!